# Using Regex in Word to Mass Modify Entries

Tags: regex, ms-word

How can I find the expression '([anumber][anumber],' in word?

I have `[0-9][0-9],` but this is repeated a few times per option therefore it removes everything in the pattern. How do i either dictate either to remove `**(**[0-9][0-9],` with that left parentheses or only remove `[0-9][0-9],` for the first instance of it in each line?

Answer (score 1):

Let's clarify your problem first:

You have something like `(0123`, `(4567`, etc., and

you want to make them `(23`, `(67`, respectively.

---

In the *replace* dialog,

put `([(])[0-9][0-9]` in the *find* box, and

put `\1` in the *replace with* box.

Actually, put `(` in the *replace with* box is just fine, but `\1` is a more flexible option.